# How do I implement a Criteria API method along with JpaRepository interface? (Spring Boot)

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jparepository

I need to implement one more method to my JpaRepository, but this one has many criterias and I would like to use Criteria API. But I can`t browse, how to do it in elegant way. So my question is in other words: Could I add a method to my JpaRepository interface and implement it somehow, to use it like generated methods?

I tried to implement this repo interface, but compiler makes me implement all methods.

Comment: That is what the `JpaSPecificationExecutor` from Spring Data JPA is for. That provides a `findAll(Specification)` method which utilizes the Criteria API but makes it easier to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use criteria in JPA you can go with JPA Specification/Predicates.

As you can add multiple conditions to it in your repository and return the expected results.

for example - under your service layer call a JPA method naming anything you want and pass the argument to it if you want to.

like :-

(result is in list case) - Service layer

```
List<your Generic> list = yourRepository.yourMethodName(your Argument);
```

Repository layer

```
default List<your Generic> yourMethodName(your Argument session) {
        return findAll(new Specification<your Generic>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<your Generic> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
                List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

                //your condition will be here-------
                //for example --
                if (session.getUserType().equalsIgnoreCase("ADMIN")) {
                    predicates.add(
                            criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("userLevel"), 3)));

                    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder
                        .and(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("isActive"), "Yes")));
                }
                
                //and many more conditions you can use here to get the expected data... like and, or, like, ge, equal, etc...
                return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
            }
        });
    }
```

for different criteria queries you can refer - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-criteria-queries

https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-and-or-criteria-predicates

if still any issue please let me know down in the comment

Comment: Thanks, one more question, is this way using Specification appropritate to bulky sql request? I mean when I have (two `with` clauses, `joun`, `function`)? I have this large sql string, maybe I would better paste it all in @Query annotation?

Comment: Bulky sql you mean to say bulky records? then yes it can handle that multiple clauses but depends how you implement and sometimes if fetched records are in thousands or more then that then you can even use pagination to it like return first or only upto 100 records or its upto you.

Comment: Actually I mean that SQL string appears to be too large with many inner clauses or sth, so it seems it`s more easy to just copy it to @Query annotation